# Is there a Scala equivalent of EnumSet/EnumMap?

Tags: scala, enums, set, scala-collections

In Java we have two nice classes: `EnumSet` for sets of `enum`s and `EnumMap` for a map whose keys are `enum`s. `EnumSet` is represented as a 64-bit word (or an array of 64-bit words) and `EnumMap` as an array of values, both indexed by the ordinal numbers of `enum`s. So insert/lookup/remove/... operations take just *O(1)* time.

**Do we have something like that in Scala - mutable or immutable?**

I found [BitSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/BitSet.html) (both mutable and immutable) which operates on integers, so I assumed there would be an efficient implementation of sets of [`Enumeration`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration).`Value`s backed up by it. But I found only `Enumeration.ValueSet`, which is [backed up by SortedSet[Int]](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L1). While that's not so bad, `BitSet` seems to be quite more efficient for this purpose.

I didn't find any optimized implementation of maps with `Enumeration.Value` as keys similar to `EnumMap`.

Comment: Unlike Java `enum`s, Scala's `Enumeration` values can have arbitrary numerical identifiers and that is why I suspect there is no direct equivalent for Java `EnumSet` and `EnumMap` in Scala.

Comment: @ghik While that's true I'd say this feature is rarely used. And when someone'd assign big numbers to values it'd be his responsibility to simply use a different `Set`/`Map` implementation.

Comment: @ghik In fact that is a source of bugs in 2.10 impl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, in 2.10 Enumeration.ValueSet uses BitSet.

`class ValueSet private[ValueSet] (private[this] var nnIds: immutable.BitSet)`

[That would be here.](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L251)

Comment: Is there also an `EnumMap` equivalent?